# My Windows system has 2 GB of 4 dedicated to hardware?

Tags: windows-10, memory, memory-error, dram

Hi guys I have this problem. My system, a 64 bit Windows 10 Pro, has only 2 GB of 4 available for the system. It's a Ddr3 1333 MHz Ram. Any idea to let all the ram visible to the system? Thank you :).

Comment: Is this RAM stick a 4 GB? Is it the only one? If this is a PC, have you tried installing it into a different slot and see? 

Did you change anything in BIOS?

Did you change anything using msconfig?

Comment: I have 2 modules of 2 GB and they works in dual channel for CPU Z. I've tried to set maximum ram in msconfig and now my system has some difficulty to start, it seems blocked on a doing recovery page. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the first thing is to remove that setting. It is not required and it causes issues. Once you do that, you can shut down the computer, restart and see if everything works fine. If it still does not, you have to look into the BIOS settings to see if there are any custom configuration (allocating memory to something else, could be graphics or so).